# Autohotkey controlsend in hidden cmd

Tags: cmd, autohotkey

I have script looks like this:

```
DetectHiddenWindows, On 
Run,%comspec% /k, , hide, pid2 
WinWait, ahk_pid %pid2% 
ControlSend, ,winscp.com script="path\to\script.txt", ahk_pid %pid2% 
sleep,3000 
;-- close hidden DOS window -- 
Process, Close, %pid2% 
Process, WaitClose, %pid2%
```

But the problem is sometimes the controlsend works and send right letters and sometimes it change the double columns to single one and sometimes change the winscp.com to winscp>com and etc which I dont know from where these letters sometimes come so Any idea how to fix this issue and make it always send the right letters cuz this really frustrate me and makes the whole script mess up.

Thanks a lot

Max

Comment: Instead of that code simply use `run, winscp.com script="path\to\script.txt",,hide` and add `exit` in your `script.txt`.

Comment: This is great solution but I still want to detect when the process has finished uploading all data to continue the script also I am kind of curious person who would love to know why this issue was occurring if anyone's know. Thanks.

Comment: So simply add a `pid` variable and use `process, waitclose` exactly the way you already have.

Comment: That's perfect with me. I won't ask again for reason for issue so as I don't be bothering but can u show me how to add pid to run command as an example if u don't mind?

Comment: You already have it, and you can read in the help file: `Run, program and arguments, , hide, pid2` << pid2 here is the Process ID variable (PID).

Comment: Oh my dumbness. I am so sorry but thanks a bunch also I guess u have helped me before but was way while before so I am sure ur a great supportive person on this forum. Thanks again

Comment: Please post your solution to your question.

Comment: I will but still experiencing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DetectHiddenWindows, on

Run, winscp.com script="path\to\script.txt", , hide, pid2

Sleep 6000

Process, close, %pid2%
Process, WaitClose, %pid2%
```

That was the best way for me to ensure all upload is done and ready to continue with the script.

Note: I could use the RunWait with /c command (which substitute the sleep command) to summarize whole script I provided above but I was afraid it still gives same issue I mentioned above so I prefered just directly using run with and process close and WaitClose commands.

Max